# How to set multiple notifications with AlarmManager apear on different time?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-notifications

Here is my problem: I have list of notifications and want to show them in diffeent time but they appear awlays together at the same time.

First call updateLabel function:

private void updateLabel(ArrayList notificationEntities){

```
    int timer = 5000;

    for (int i = 0; i < notificationEntities.size(); i++) {

        Notification notification = addNotification(notificationEntities.get(i));
        scheduleNotification(notificationEntities.get(i).getId(), notification, (long) timer);

        timer += 10000;
    }

}
```

---

Then create the notification:

private Notification addNotification(NotificationEntity notificationEntity) {

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, default_notification_channel_id)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_android_24)
            .setContentTitle("Notifications Example")
            .setContentText("This is a test notification for " + notificationEntity.getType() + " with id " + notificationEntity.getId())
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_REMINDER)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{0, 1000, 1000})
            .setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);

    return notification.build();
}
```

---

And then scheduleNotification:

private void scheduleNotification(int notificationId, Notification notification, long delay){

```
    int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationPublisher.class);

    notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationId);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION, notification);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent
            .getBroadcast(this, requestID, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, delay, pendingIntent);

}
```

---

Here is my NotificationPublisher class:

public class NotificationPublisher  extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
public static final String NOTIFICATION = "myNotification";
public static final String NOTIFICATION_ID = "myNotification-id";
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = intent.getParcelableExtra(NOTIFICATION);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){

        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(ClientHomepage.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "Channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        channel.setDescription("This is just notification");
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);

    }
    int id = intent.getIntExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, 0);
    notificationManager.notify(id, notification);
}
```

### }

My problem is that all the notifications apper at the same time, not one after one.
I've tried changing requestID, but it doesn't help, I've also tries changing PendingIntent flag and this also doesn't help. Hope you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you added wrong time in this line of code

scheduleNotification(notificationEntities.get(i).getId(), notification, (long) timer);

instead of `(long)timer`
you have to add `System.currentTimeinMillis()+timer`
it will solve your problem

Comment: I've tried to change it with System.currentTimeinMillis()+timer, but in this way it gets current time in miliseconds and when then adds the timer and the value is something like 1641664308166 and I don't even recieve the notifications (or I'm gonna recieve them after a long time). My idea is to set 3 notifications one after one with 1 minute time between them. Hope you have other idias

Comment: I've tried with changing this line also:
 AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, delay, pendingIntent);

Whith:
 AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + delay, pendingIntent);

In that way RTC + 1min, the first notification comes then the second with 1min between, but the third come right togeher with the second and there is no time 1min between the second and third